# User interface development using qt designer python programming

Tags: python, python-3.6

Im pretty new to qt designer using python. Im having a hard time inserting data into mysql  database from radio button and combo box wigdets.  Can you give me an example how to insert data from this wigdets and putting it into variable in order to use into query?  Thanks

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import pymysql

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def insertData(self):
        dropDown = self.comboBox.addItems(self.comboBox)

        conn = pymysql.connect("localhost","root","warren110598","dss")
        with conn:
            cur = conn.cursor()
            cur.execute("INSERT INTO ml (rank) values ('%s')" %(''.join(dropDown)))
            print("euuu")


    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(426, 302)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(242, 255, 225);")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.comboBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 120, 69, 22))
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 120, 111, 16))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 170, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.insertData)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 426, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "dae"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "eu"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(2, _translate("MainWindow", "mapondo  na"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ma mobile legends?"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Submit"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Show us the code that you are having problem with.

Comment: my code are in my question. i just edited